# postman - tie Environment to request

Tags: api, postman, onelogin

When I set an environment, is sets it for all requests I have open. This is annoying, as I'm working on several things at a time that use different environments.

Is there a way to tell postman "Use this environment for ONLY this request, and leave the rest alone"?

Comment: No, is the short answer. You could probably do something with Flows as that creates Send Request blocks that have an environment option.

Comment: Things would get very messy if you set env by request. What would be great is if you could run multiple instances of Postman and set each instance to the desired env.